# Mainframe file naming in java ftp code

Tags: ftp, filepath, mainframe

Say I have a file file.txt on my mainframe host xxx.xxx.xxx.xx created by user QWERTY in the path TEST. I would like to ftp this file from mainframe to my unix machine. When I run the code `fsDataInputStream=ftpFileSystem.open(new Path ("ftp://QWERTY@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx'TEST/file.txt'")  );`

the error I get is "Path ftp://QWERTY@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx'TEST/file.txt' is a directory."

On giving `fsDataInputStream = ftpFileSystem.open(new Path('TEST/file.txt'), 1000);`

I get the error : File 'QWERTY.'/'TEST/file.txt does not exist. It appends the 'QWERTY.'/' on its own.

Any pointers on how to give this file path name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working !!
The problem was that I was using fTpFileSystem which was on its own appending the username to the connection URL . 
I instead used other apis of FTP system .